# ipad bbc app with horizontal tableview?

Tags: ipad, uitableview

The BBC app has a main display that lets you slide stories left to right, it appears to be a horizontal tableview instead of vertical. It has the same 'gravity' like bounce as well but horizontal.

ANy idea how this is done? I'd like to have this on a new app we're making

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they just implement it with the UIScrollView.

Have also found this on the net. See if this can help:

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView